# Force Legend to Always display in ArcGIS Online Web App

Tags: arcgis-online, legend

Is it possible to force the legend in ArcGIS Online Web App (Web App Builder, not developer edition) to always display the legend. Perhaps in the JSON file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working, via using the default Web App Builder template.

- Selected the "Jewelry Box Theme"
  [image]

This displays a empty panel which you can select a widget (Chose the Legend Widget).

[image]

[image]

Thus the legend will be presented by default.